# How to implement an interface, whose two instances can depend on each other, in a skeletal implementation, i.e. class, without downcast?

Tags: java, oop, circular-dependency

Given a `Person` interface:

```
public interface Person {
    Person getSpouse();
    void marry(Person spouse);
}
```

I made a *skeletal implementation*:

```
public abstract class AbstractPerson implements Person {
    private Person spouse;
    @Override
    public Person getSpouse() {
        return spouse;
    }
    @Override
    public void marry(Person spouse) {
        this.spouse = spouse;
        ((MarriedPerson) spouse).setSpouse(this);//forced to downcast
    }
    protected void setSpouse(Person spouse) {
        this.spouse = spouse;
    }
}
```

The drawback of calling the `marry(Person spouse)` with the *skeletal implementation* is the *argument* `spouse` has to be an instance of `AbstractPerson`. However, if the `spouse.marry(this)` is called inside the `marry()`, it will loop endlessly and wind up with *stack overflow error*

**Question: is it possible to implement the marry(Person spouse) without downcast? how?**

Comment: Why are `getSpouse` and `marry` declared in `Person`? Those methods belong to the concept `MarriedPerson`.

Comment: `public interface Person<T extends Person<T>> {void marry(T spouse); ...}`

Comment: `((MarriedPerson) spouse).setSpouse(spouse);` are you making someone marry themselves? `spouse.setSpouce(this)`?

Comment: If you wanted to simply highlight the technical issue rather than design the perfect marriage model then you could profit from double dispatch

Comment: I dont think you can `Person` does not have a method `setSpouse` so naturally you cannot call it. You could place `setSpouse` in the person interface, It would make sense since you already define a `getSpouse`

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I tried with your solution, it works. But then tried also only `<T extends Person>`, it works as well

Comment: @MitchelPaulin adding `setSpouse` to the `Person` interface belies the Demeter Law and thus might confuse the client using the `Person` interface

Comment: @akuzminykh no, in most countries a married person may not marry, they must get divorced first. (For those [countries that allow multiple spouses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_polygamy), only men may have multiple spouses, all of which must be female, but since the model has at most 1 spouse and no gender, I think we can ignore this scenario).

Comment: @Bohemian Not sure what your point is. *Person* is a concept and *MarriedPerson* is a subset of that concept. `spouse` should be an attribute of elements in that subset. The method `marry` is debatable though when I think about it .. a *Person* marries someone. How much this can be generalized in regard of countries and whatever is not scope of the question.

Comment: @akuzminykh all explained in my answer

Answer (score 4):

You are over thinking it. Your mistake is having a `Person` interface, `MarriedPerson` and `AbstractPerson` classes. The act of getting married doesn't alter your "personess", so it shouldn't mutate the instance into another class (ie `MarriedPerson`). Rather, it changes the *state* of the instance, such that `isMarried()` would be true.

Scrap the lot and have a single class:

```
public class Person {
    private Person spouse;  // getters/setters not shown

    public boolean isMarried() {
        return spouse != null;
    }

    public void marry(Person spouse) {
        this.spouse = spouse;
        spouse.spouse = this;
    }

    public void divorce() {
        this.spouse = null;
        spouse.spouse = null;
    }
}
```

---

Side note:

A more universally accurate model would have `List<Person> spouces`, since [some coutries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_polygamy) allow mutliple spouses. Gender also comes into play as those coutries typically only allow *men* to have multiple spouses, and all those spouses must be female (gay marriage is not legal in many countries), so a `Man` class would have a `List<Female>` and a `Female` would have `Man spouse`.
Not naming the feminine version `Woman` was deliberate, as in some coutries marriage of a female is allowed before they complete puberty, and so technically would not be classed as a woman.

Comment: +1 for the additional information. This is a good example why you should always be aware of requirements. Otherwise you may have problems with to simple design or to overengineered design. *Side note:* One method is missing: `switchSpouse` ;)

Comment: @Bohemian The example I gave is actually not the real case. The real case is on a large scale that there are many *sub-classes* of `Person`, so a *skeletal implementation* is necessary

Comment: This model permits polygamy and it's suitable for around the 30% of the countries.

Comment: @TomásDenisReyesSánchez the skeletal implementation class is now called `AbstractPerson`, i.e. my focus is not about the law about marital law but how to implement dependency on each other in a compact way

Answer (score 0):

You might consider an aggregate collection of Mix-In subclasses of a class PeronAttribute (or implements a PersonAttribute interface).  This is similar to the Java LDAP Attribute/BasicAttribute implementation which allows for dynamic extensions to both behavior and structural characteristics.  Traditional OO (java/C++) lean toward what I call "static class hierarchies".  They are great in terms of compile-time checking (vs delayed runtime issues) and easy to model in UML because the class definitions are like DDL (to draw a parallel to RDBMS' and tables).  This approach bridges the gap to more fully dynamic languages like JavaScript (ref: the rise of NodeJS and reincarnation of Netscape livewire from late 1990's)

LDAP reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/Attribute.html

GoF reference:
https://martinfowler.com/bliki/GangOfFour.html
https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/
patterns : behavioral, structural, creational

Livewire reference (1997):
https://www.drdobbs.com/database/livewire-web-to-database-solutions-part/184410393
https://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/html/tutorial/getstart.htm